# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command windows 10

Tags: cmd

after compiling files using gcc on windows 10
while executing using ./a.out says '.' not recognised.

I have already set gcc path in environment

Comment: `.\ ` But the `.` is unnecessary. So is `.\ `. Paths that don't start `\\ ` or `driveletter:` are always relative to current path.

Comment: the default executable file extension in Windows is exe, not out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `./a.out` command would work on a linux system. 
[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4430/274118) is a good explanation of how and why that works.

As the message was saying the `.` command does not exist in the windows command line.

On windows just type the name, `a.out` of your file and hit return.
If your application was properly built and is executable, it should run without any problem. Otherwise it will try to open it with the default application for that extension.

Answer (score 11):

in windows use : .\
in mac use : ./
Hope it will help